# How to change the value of an object property in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, object

I'll start by showing my code.

```
var modules:Object = new Object();
modules = DPServices.getModules.lastResult;
for each (var item:Object in modules){
    if(item.menu == 0){
        // Don't know what to do here!!
    }
}
modulesDG.dataProvider = modules;
```

By the way this is ActionScript 3.

What I am trying to do is change the value from a 0 to 'No' or a 1 to 'Yes'. I have tried `modules.menu = 'no'`, `modules.item.menu = 'no'`, and `modules.@menu = 'no'`. So how do I change this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is modules an object of objects? If not, this should be fine:

```
item.menu = 'no';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help for some reason I thought that item was a new object and the changes will only affect it and not the module object.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change menu to 1 if it's 0?

Isn't it enough to just do:

```
if(item.menu == 0){
    item.menu = 1;
}
```

Though I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for.